# How is Big O of fast exponentiation O(log n)?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, exponential-function, exponentiation

I am reading Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual, and he says that if we change $a^n$ to $(a^{n/2})^2$, the exponent is halved at the cost of, at most, 2 multiplications so the algorithm is now $O(\log n)$.

I can't understand how it's $O(\log n)$. We are performing $n/2+1$ multiplications during exponentiation so shouldn't the algorithm be $O(n/2)$?

Comment: You wouldn't compute $a^{n/2}$ by doing the $n/2$ multiplications. You would apply the same idea recursively. If $n/2$ is even, then you compute $a^{n/2}$ by squaring $a^{n/4}$. If $n/2$ is odd, you would compute $a^{n/2}$ by squaring $a^{(n/2-1)/2}$ and multiplying the result by $a$.

Comment: The steps that you need to do are given by the base $2$ representation of $n$. When there is a $0$ you square and when there is a $1$ you multiply by $a$. So, the number of multiplications is the number of digits of $n$ in base $2$, which are about $\log_2(n)$.

Comment: @plop could you please elaborate on how one would apply the idea recursively?

Comment: The author only mentions the main idea without details. Apparently , he was too lazy to explain the idea detailed , maybe because it is a standard method to calculate $a^b\mod c$ with relatively small $b$

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Comment: Is this the right way to think about it: There are 2 multiplications $\log_2(n)$ times. So total $2\log_2(n)$ steps => O(n) ?

Comment: Don’t you mean $O(\log n)$? Still, it’s 2 _at most_, governed by the 1s in the exponent’s binary representation.

Comment: Yes O(log(n))* .